# Linewidth and cannot call "plot" with arguments

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to tinker a bit with the standard stochastic indicator. I want to use different colors and linewidths depending on %K, and %D being over/under a horizontal line. However I can't get it to work. Below is a minimal example (I left the %D part out because it's practically the same.) I get the following error message:

```
Cannot call 'plot' with arguments (series[float], title=literal string, color=series[color], linewidth=series[integer]); available overloads: plot(series[float], const string, series[color], input integer, input integer, input bool, input integer, input float, series[integer], input bool, series[float], const bool, input integer, const integer, string) => plot; plot(<arg_series_type>, const string, <arg_color_type>, input integer, input integer, input bool, input integer, input float, series[integer], input bool, series[float], const bool, input integer, const integer, string) => plot
```

```
//@version=4
study(title="Stochastic", shorttitle="Stoch", format=format.price, precision=2, resolution="")
periodK = input(14, title="K", minval=1)
periodD = input(3, title="D", minval=1)
smoothK = input(3, title="Smooth", minval=1)
upTHR = input(80, title="Up Threshold", minval=0)
downTHR = input(20, title="Down Threshold", minval=0)
k = sma(stoch(close, high, low, periodK), smoothK)
h0 = hline(upTHR, "Upper Band", color=#606060)
h1 = hline(downTHR, "Lower Band", color=#606060)

kColor = k >= 80 or k <= 20 ? #0d47a1 : #2196f3
kLinewidth = k >= 80 or k <= 20 ? 2 : 1

plot(k, title="%K", color=kColor, linewidth=kLinewidth)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using a mutable variable `kLinewidth` for the linewidth argument of the `plot()` function. That argument must be a fixed integer.

This will compile:

```
//@version=4
study(title="Stochastic", shorttitle="Stoch", format=format.price, precision=2, resolution="")
periodK = input(14, title="K", minval=1)
periodD = input(3, title="D", minval=1)
upTHR = input(80, title="Up Threshold", minval=0)
downTHR = input(20, title="Down Threshold", minval=0)

smoothK = 5 // added to get it compiled.

k = sma(stoch(close, high, low, periodK), smoothK)
h0 = hline(upTHR, "Upper Band", color=#606060)
h1 = hline(downTHR, "Lower Band", color=#606060)

kColor = k >= 80 or k <= 20 ? #0d47a1 : #2196f3
kLinewidth = k >= 80 or k <= 20 ? 2 : 1

// plot(k, title="%K", color=kColor, linewidth=kLinewidth)
plot(k, title="%K", color=kColor, linewidth=1)
```

Update 10 dec 2020:

I guess you could use a trick by plotting 2 lines on top of eachother.
You plot the thinner line as normal (continuously), and you plot the thicker line only at the moments it's supposed to be thicker. The moments that it's not supposed to be thicker, you just stop plotting it by plotting the `na` value.

Like this:

```
//@version=4
study(title="Stochastic", shorttitle="Stoch", format=format.price, precision=2, resolution="")
periodK = input(14, title="K",              minval=1)
periodD = input( 3, title="D",              minval=1)
upTHR   = input(80, title="Up Threshold",   minval=0)
downTHR = input(20, title="Down Threshold", minval=0)

smoothK = 5 // added to get it compiled.

k  = sma(stoch(close, high, low, periodK), smoothK)
h0 = hline(upTHR, "Upper Band", color=#606060)
h1 = hline(downTHR, "Lower Band", color=#606060)

kColor = k >= 80 or k <= 20 ? #0d47a1 : #2196f3
kLinewidth = k >= 80 or k <= 20 ? 2 : 1

// plot(k, title="%K", color=kColor, linewidth=kLinewidth)
plot(k, title="%K", color=kColor, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_linebr)
plot(kLinewidth == 2 ? k : na, title="%K", color=kColor, linewidth=5, style=plot.style_linebr)
```

Which yields:

[image]

Maybe that could be a solution (more like a workaround actually) to your problem.

Comment: Hello Bjorn. I see. And there's no way to transform the mutable into a fixed integer? I couldn't find one. I guess that is my problem isn't it.

Comment: Updated my answer with a possible workaround.

Comment: You know what. I just woke up. Checked the docu again, and thought the same workaround could work. Thanks for the help.